# Degreasing an Aluminium engine with drain unclogger

Tags: aluminum, degreaser

I am rebuilding an engine (which is mainly made of aluminium) And I need to degrease all the parts. I don't have any proper degreaser available but even if I had some, I doubt it would do anything. I found that drain unclogger works nicely but it creates a thin corrosion layer on the aluminium (which can be rubbed away with a sponge).

Is it safe for the engine to use drain unclogger and rinse it off in less than three minutes from application?

Comment: No, I would NOT use "drain unclogger" which is generally sodium hydroxide.  It reacts with Aluminum and will damage things like the inside of the cylinders, the top of the cylinder block, and other places where you might need to have an undamaged surface.  Use a proper degreasing solvent.  In a pinch many people use kerosene (in a well ventilated area of course).  Do NOT use gasoline!

Comment: @jwh20 I was not going to use it on these parts.  Would it be safe to use it on the engine shell/oil pan?

Comment: As I said, I would NOT use it on any engine parts.  Use an appropriate product.

Comment: I'm not clear why you say that engine degreaser would not do anything.  My experience is that, used properly, it will cut through even the toughest grease and dirt.

Comment: @jwh20 I don't use degreaser frequently but I remember it was quite difficult to completely degrease parts that were way cleaner than those I am working with at the moment.

Comment: Given you have been fitting pistons then most of these parts should have already been cleaned block, crank, pistons, rings con-rods, bearings etc

Comment: @Solar Mike Only the piston and the cylinder have been cleaned.